# Automatic Goal Seek Over Range of Cells

Tags: excel, range, automatic-properties, vba

I want to apply goal seek across several rows when there is a change to any cell in the work sheet.  I want to apply this from row 7 to row 11.  The first problem I have is that excel is crashing each time I run this.  I am just starting to learn VBA so any help is much apreciated.  Thank you!

My code is below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
CheckGoalSeek
End Sub

Private Sub CheckGoalSeek()
Range("T7").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("V7")
End Sub
```

Comment: What is in cell T7 and cell V7?

Comment: Cell T7 is breakage fee which is equal to the difference between the present value of a series of cash flows discounted at rate 'R' and the present value of a series of cash flows discounted at Treasury Rate plus a premium X.  Cell V7 is the premium X.

Comment: Use the Worksheet_Change event. Looks like goal seek iteration is triggering a worksheet recalculation which is triggering a new goal seek ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be triggering an infinite loop: worksheet calculation -> goal seek calculation ->  worksheet calculation -> ...

One option is to change the event that triggers the goal seek.

I would recommend the Worksheet_Change event. The event code would be the same except for the sub declaration, which would be  `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`.

A simple `For` loop will perform the Goal Seek on the different rows:

```
 Option Explicit

 Private Sub CheckGoalSeek()
    Dim i as Long
    For i = 7 to 11
        Range("T"& i).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("V"& i)
    Next
 End Sub
```