# Goal Seek Macro with moving Goal and Seek variables

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2011

I have a Goal Seek Macro:

```
Sub GOALSEEK()
    Range("K25").GOALSEEK Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("K10")
End Sub
```

That works for 2015Q4, cell `K25` at 0%.

I want to adapt the macro for moving Goal and Seek variables.

The moving Goal will be stored in `C25` (0, 0.01, 0.05, etc), and the moving Seek will be dependent on `C6` (Q2, Q3, Q4, which will map to I25, J25, K25, respectively).

[image]

**EDIT**

After some tinkering, I just discovered that the moving Goal can be implemented by changing `Goal:=0` to `Goal:=Range("Cell")`:

```
Sub GOALSEEK()
    Range("K25").GOALSEEK Goal:=Range("C25"), ChangingCell:=Range("K10")
End Sub
```

Still don't know how to make Seek move.

Comment: Do you have a question? Did you have a question, figure it out, then post your answer as your EDIT?

Comment: I was just tinkering after I posted the question and figured out how to adjust the Goal. But I still don't know how to adjust the moving Seek.

Comment: See if this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240176/automatic-goal-seek-over-range-of-cells

Comment: How do you decide which cell to perform the seek on? I can think of a couple ways to do this.

Comment: @Kyle. The seeks will be for Q2, Q3, Q4 as decided/picked in cell C6 (and concatenated in C7 to match I9, J9, K9). If Q3, K25 and K10 will change to J25 and J10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put some conditional logic in your code like below to make the decision on the fly based on which quarter is entered in cell C6.

```
Sub GOALSEEK()

Dim gseek, chngcell as Range

If Range("C6") = "Q2" Then
   Set gseek = Range("I25")
   Set chngcell = Range("I10")
Elseif Range("C6") = "Q3" Then
   Set gseek = Range("J25")
   Set chngcell = Range("J10")
Elseif Range("C6") = "Q4" Then
   Set gseek = Range("K25")
   Set chngcell = Range("K10")
End If

gseek.GOALSEEK Goal:=Range("C25"), ChangingCell:=chngcell

End Sub
```

You could further this to set another range variable to the cell you want to change as well. Let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Almost! But K10 should also adjust to "Q2" Then "I10", "Q3" Then "J10"

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following approach:

Define new named range call it for example `SeekCell` and in Refers To enter:

```
=INDEX($I$25:$K$25,1,MATCH("2015"&$C$6,$I$9:$K$9))
```

Define new named range call it for example `ChangeCell` and in Refers To enter:

```
=INDEX($I$10:$K$10,1,MATCH("2015"&$C$6,$I$9:$K$9))
```

Define new named range call it for example `GoalCell` and in Refers To enter:

```
=$C$25
```

In the VBA code use:

```
Range("SeekCell").GOALSEEK  Goal:=Range("GoalCell"), ChangingCell:=Range("ChangeCell")
```